# How to filter simplexml_load_file foreach loop?

Tags: php, xml, foreach, preg-match

I have the following php code:

```
<?php
$website_url = 'domain.com/sitemap.xml';
$xml=simplexml_load_file(''. $website_url.'') or die("Error: Cannot create object");
foreach($xml->url as $val)
 {
   echo $val->loc.  '<br>';
 }
```

It works fine, I get the url's from the xml sitemap file, but I want to filter positive matches (and after that negative matches), for example only lines that contain "apple" and "juice" (and for negative, only lines that don't contain "rss" or "sitemap") . I tried few ways to do it with preg_match but without success, I get blank page results or 500 error.
 The xml file (a simple sitemap.xml file) I extract and want to filter has around 20000 lines/url's

Comment: Show us your attempts and we can try to find where you went wrong.

Comment: Does the string need to contain _both_ keywords, or do you mean _any_ of the keywords? (Is it `and` or `or`?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use http://php.net/strpos for match. you can also check for rss and sitemap:

```
foreach($xml->url as $val)
 {
   $url = $val->loc;
    if(strpos($url, 'apple') !== FALSE && strpos($url, 'juice') !== FALSE) {
        echo "keyword found in URL\n";
        break;
    }
    else {
        echo "keyword not found\n";
    }
 }
```

Comment: Is there any way to get AND (&&) or OR (||) from $variable inside strops?

Answer (score 0):

Can use `xpath()` for this:

- [`SimpleXMLElement::xpath`](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php) — Runs XPath query on XML data

In particular [`contains()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-contains):

```
foreach($urlset->xpath('url[contains(., "foo")]') as $url) {
```

To negate, wrap the expression in [`not()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-not):

```
foreach($urlset->xpath('url[not(contains(., "foo"))]') as $url) {
```